# Create ListItem for each member of SharePoint 2010 Group using SPD Workflows

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, list, workflow, groups

Is it possible to create a ListItem for each member of a SP 2010 group using the SharePoint Designer Workflow Actions?

Let's say i have 5 people in a group, now the workflow has to create a simple ListItem for each member, with the username as title.

Background: Customer wants a Siteworkflow (not on document/list level. no item context), designed with SPD, that creates a ListItem in a list for each person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no out-of-the-box action available in Sharepoint designer to get users in Sharepoint group. What you have to do is to call a web- service to get the details of the user in group.

You can download following Activity to call web service :

http://ilovesharepoint.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Call%20a%20Web%20Service%20Action

And follow the following steps to get users http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/anavijai/how-to-get-all-the-users-from-a-specific-sharepoint-group-us/.

After that you can use CreatelistItem action to create listitems.